# I want the Firefox icon on the launcher to open a new window if there is no Firefox window open on the current workspace

Tags: unity, firefox, launcher, workspaces

I'm using Ubuntu Raring Ringtail, with three monitors and four workspaces. Currently, if I click on the Firefox button on the launcher and Firefox is already running but there is no Firefox window on the current workspace, it switches to a workspace which already has an open Firefox window.

I don't want it to do that. When I click the button it should open a new Firefox window on the current workspace, if there isn't already one. Is it possible to configure the launcher to work that way?

Comment: Middle-click launches a new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The launcher already is configured that way:

Hold down Shift while clicking the Firefox Icon, and you get a new Instance, instead of switching to the current one..

If you need more help with Unitys functions, hold down the super key and wait for the Help to pop up.

Have Fun.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I had no idea. Where can I learn about all these useful key combinations (besides the ones on the launcher help page, although admittedly that's a good start :))? There must be many more that would be handy to know.

Comment: It is not that much. The on-screen help pretty much covers it all. But there are some tricks with the mouse that are not covered in the on.screen help but here: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/list-of-ubuntu-unity-keyboard-shortcuts.html